# NZEC error in C code on codechef

Tags: c, runtime-error

It shows runtime error NZEC in this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
int i,d=0,x;
char buffer [256];
//printf ("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%s",buffer);

i = atoi (buffer);
while(i>0)
{
x=i%10;
i=i/10;
switch(x)
{
case 0:d=d+6;
break;
case 1:d=d+2;
break;
case 2: d=d+5;
break;
case 3: d=d+5;
break;
case 4: d=d+4;
break;
case 5: d=d+5;
break;
case 6: d=d+6;
break;
case 7: d=d+3;
break;
case 8: d=d+7;
break;
case 9: d=d+6;
break;
}
}
//printf("The no of dashes are :");
//printf("%d",d);

return d;
}
```

but the question demands the number 'd' to be returned by the function.
I don't know how to resolve the error.
Please help.

[BTW This is the problem statement](http://www.codechef.com/CDER2015/problems/DISPLAY/)

Comment: Do you know what an NZEC is? If you do, then what don't you understand; if you don't, then that's the question you should be asking :-)

Comment: Read the problem statement again. You need to write a _function_ that returns the number of dashes, not a _program_ that returns that number. The `main` function should always return 0 (or nothing) unless there's an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NZEC -> non zero exit code.

A NZEC is a mechanism to signal that your code ran into some kind of error such as out of memory or Segmentation Fault error.

In your code, the last line does a

```
return d;
```

`d` is incremented in the code after it is initially assigned to `0`.

Since your `main()` returns value `>0`, it is throwing `NZEC error`.

Change this to

```
return 0;
```

to resolve the issue.

Comment: but the problem statement asks to return the value of d in the function

Comment: @singhsterabhi , in codechef, what they meant is output the value and not  return it. BTW if you try some of the PRACTICE problems on codechef, youll get used to it.